# Async await & embedded interop type error

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, office-interop

I got method which runs some word document report generation.

I tought that there is no way to do it synchronously, so, I decided to make `async await` method for that.

But for some resaon *Visual Studio* outputs this error

> Cannot be used across assembly boundaries because it has a generic type parameters that is an embedded interop type

`Embed Interop Types` set to false and if I use simple synchronous method its seems okay

[image]

Code of functions is here

```
        public Document GenerateReport(AptTemplateType type)
        {
            try
            {
                var builder = _curentrBuilderFactory.GetBuilder(type);

                var generatedDocument = builder.CreateDocument();
                return generatedDocument;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }

        public async Task<Document> GenerateReportAsync(AptTemplateType type)
        {
            WordDocumentBuilder builder;

            try
            {
                builder = _curentrBuilderFactory.GetBuilder(AptTemplateType.UseCaseModelSurvey);
                var generatedDocument = await Task.Run(() => builder.CreateDocument());
                return generatedDocument;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

**UPD**:

`CreateDocument` simple defenition:

```
public virtual Document CreateDocument()
{
    return WordApplication.Documents.Add(ref OMissing, ref OMissing, ref OMissing, ref OMissing);
}
```

Comment: You don't want `.Result` in there; it's `await` *or* `.Result`, not both, and whenever possible, you want to use `await` instead.  Also you're ignoring your `type` parameter in the async version of the method.

Comment: @sellotape yep, about 'result' just ignore it was playing aroud checking will the red highlight gone

Comment: Can you show us the definition of `CreateDocument()`?

Comment: Also is Embed Interop Types false for *all* references to that assembly in all projects in your solution?

Comment: @sellotape well, okay, I'll update the question

Comment: @sellotape there is only one reference, so, yes